# Finding the number of subspaces of a certain dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime. Find the number of subspaces of dimension 1 and 2 of the three dimenstional vector space $\mathbb{F}_p^3$. I know that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is generated by all elements relatively prime to $p$, but two subspaces are supposed to be equal if their bases can be expressed as linear combinations of each other. So aren't all 1 dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^3$ isomorphic to each other and in particular $\mathbb{F}_p$? Similarly for subspaces of dimension 2, you need two elements to generate a subset but all are linear combinations of one another so there can only be one.

This doesn't sound right, but I'm not sure what to do. I can't seem to find any information that would help figure this out.

Comment: Congratulations on question id $2^{16}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all subspaces of a given dimension are isomorphic to each other, but the question does not ask you to count subspaces *up to isomorphism*, it just asks you to count subspaces.  So e.g. the subspace spanned by $(0,1,1)$ and the subspace spanned by $(1,0,1)$ are different.
On the other hand, the subspace spanned by $(0,1,1)$ and the subspace spanned by $(0,2,2)$ (if $p \ne 2$) are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was making it a little more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this, subspaces of one dimension can only have 1 coordinate non-zero, and since in $\mathbb{F}_p$ all elements are linear combinations of one another, then there are only 3 subspaces. Then in your example, the subspace spanned by $(0,1,1)$ and the subspace spanned by $(0,1,2)$ would not be equal.

Comment: I think you're still confused.  What do you mean by "only have 1 coordinate non-zero"?

Comment: You're right, I am. Fortunately, I managed to find a good section in Dummit and Foote that is working a lot better than the notes provided by my professor. I think I meant that a subspace spanned by (0,1,1) is not one-dimensional since there are two coordinates that are non-zero, which is definitely not correct. The dimension of a (finite) subspace is equal to the order of the basis, so if the basis is generated by a single element, then the subspace generated by that basis is one-dimensional.